# How to install gtk2.0 with OPKG package manager?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, gtk2, opkg

I'm using IMX6DL, there the OS which it is running on it contains OPKG package manager, but while install gtk2.0 I'm getting

```
$ opkg install libgtk-2.0-dev
opkg_prepare_url_for_install: Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'gtk+2.0'
```

Can anyone tell me how manage this?